# Requested Store not found while applying new theme after updating magento 1.9 to 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I've successfully upgraded magento 1 to 2. Everything is working fine, all data has been imported.
But when i go to apply my theme, i get the error

**Requested Store is not found**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check stores exist?

Comment: May i know what are all the steps you followed for 1.9 to 2.1.7 update?

Comment: @kunj they do exist

Comment: @zus All the steps mentioned in Devdocs

Comment: @DaniyalAhmed OKay, let me check, thank you.

Comment: @zus the stores are okay in stores->configuration and everyother place, it is only happening when i apply new themes, even my new created stores are doing this.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmed Did you check console error and log error?

Comment: @zus There are no errors there

Answer (score 0):

Run below sql query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 1 WHERE code='Erecycleronline';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 1 WHERE name='Main Website Store';
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 1 WHERE code='Default Store View';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Tried doesn't work